# Can I use Mathematica to derive these induction equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following model

[image]

T + 1 dates, t = 0, 1, ...,T

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This was all solved by hand and I wanted to ask if Mathematica can be used to do the job instead?

If so, what commands are helpful?

Comment: Maybe, you'd have to provide a clear description of symbols used and convention etc. There is also a standard question: have you tried anything?

Comment: @Kuba This more of a general question. I am not looking for any code solution. I am just wondering if Mathematica is able to something like backward induction. I looked online for it but couldn’t find anything